# Obtener ruta por defecto

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7, angular6

estoy tratando de que se muestre en mi pagina una ruta al iniciar. Pero estoy teniendo algunos problemas con esta parte. Este es mi codigo:
Quiero que al cargar la pagina automaticamente me rediriga a una vista en concreto. Estoy usando lazy loading , aunque es un proyecto pequeño.
Tengo un modulo Home, que tiene varios componenentes que se mostrararan depediendo la ruta se debe mostrar el contenido.

Estas son mis 2 archivos de rutas.

Home.routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AlbumComponent } from './album/album.component';
import { ArtistComponent } from './artist/artist.component';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { RecentComponent } from './recent/recent.component';
import { SongComponent } from './song/song.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'albums',
        component: AlbumComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'artist',
        component: ArtistComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'recent',
        component: RecentComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'songs',
        component: SongComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'artist',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {}
```

App.routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/home',
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}


Esto es lo que quiero q se muestre al inicio, cuando entro la ruta que me carga es localHost:4200/home
Estaba viendo si se podia usar pathMath:full o algo parecido pero no logro solucionarlo con eso.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

{
path: '',
redirectTo: 'home/artist', //o '/home/artist'
pathMatch: 'full',
},
Espero que te sirva.
Saludos.